# Inserting IEnumerable collection in an object using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Hi i have following classes

```
public class bizOrg
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int p_id { get; set; }
    public virtual product product { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<newStructure> newStructure { get; set; }
}
```

And

```
public class newStructure
{
    public int project_id { get; set; }
    public string a_name { get; set; }
    public string a_phone { get; set; }
    public virtual product product { get; set; }
}
```

I have following Linq statement

```
 var acc = (from c in db.p_account
                            where c.p_id == id
                            select new bizOrg
                            {
                                p_id = c.product.id,
                                name = c.name,
                               newStructure=  new newStructure
                                  {    
                                    a_name = c.name,
                                    a_phone = c.phone,                                 
                                   }
                            });
```

On the above linq statement I get intelicense error saying

```
Cannot implicitly convert type newStructure to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<newStructure>' . An explicit conversion exists
```

Please let me know how to correct this error. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`newStructure` needs to be a collection.  If you just have a flat list (meaning the underlying collection will just have one item), then you can do:

```
 var acc = (from c in db.p_account
            where c.p_id == id
            select new bizOrg
            {
                p_id = c.product.id,
                name = c.name,
               newStructure=  new List<newStructure>
                  { new newStructure()   
                    {  
                       a_name = c.name,
                       a_phone = c.phone,                                 
                     }
                   }
            });
```

If there needs to be some other organization (e.g. group by `name` or some other property), then you'll need to provide more detail in the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

This bit of code;

```
            select new bizOrg
                        {
                            p_id = c.product.id,
                            name = c.name,
                           newStructure=  new newStructure
                              {    
                                a_name = c.name,
                                a_phone = c.phone,                                 
                               }
                        });
```

Is creating a single `newStructure` instance and trying to assign it to a property of type `IEnumerable<newStructure>` instead do;

```
    newStructure = new { new newStructure() { a_name = c.name, a_phone = c.phone } }
```

which just puts your singleton into a collection, using a static initializer.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to create a new `IEnumerable<newStructure>` in your linq statement.  It expects a collection of objects, where you are only assigning a single object instead of a collection of a single object.

```
var acc = (from c in db.p_account
                            where c.p_id == id
                            select new bizOrg
                            {
                                p_id = c.product.id,
                                name = c.name,
                               newStructure=  new List<newStructure>{
                                    new newStructure{    
                                      a_name = c.name,
                                      a_phone = c.phone,                                 
                                     }
                                   }
                            });
```